# How can I get a list of records missing from each group of records?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of Items, which each have a list of Settings, and I am trying to get all the items to have the same list of settings, so out of the current record set, I want to extract a list of settings that need to be added.

Ideally just using excel formulas and manipulation (and not VBA), how can I achieve this?

I have tried going through manually and comparing items against each other, but it feels like there should be a much faster programmatic way of doing this. Here is the example set of records:

```
Item       Setting
----       --------
BS         EDADM
BS         EDDIS
BS         EDREG
BS         EEPRE
CC         EDADM
CC         EDREG
LB         EDDIS
LB         EDREG
LB         EEPRE
```

Based upon the example set, I expect the output to be:

```
Item       Setting
----       --------
CC         EDDIS
CC         EEPRE
LB         EDADM
```

Comment: I don't understand your example output at all based on your example input and explanation. Please reword the question, or explain step by step how the example output is determined.

Comment: Programmatic, yes, but not without VBA. You can't have programmatic without code. This too hard for regular formulas. You can create a pivot table to visualise the missing bits.

Comment: Oh, I'm coming back to this and I see now. You want to generate a list of all possible Item/Setting combinations that aren't used in your original list. I agree with @teylyn that this is probably not worth doing with formulas alone. Even with a bunch of helper cells, it probably isn't worth it.